# Sum of Pending Amounts Based on Customer with each line on display

Tags: mysql

I am looking to display the details of all pending invoices along with a column which shows the total of the pending invoices of a particular customer but I am unable to find a way to do the same. Here is what I am trying to do:

```
+----------+------------+---------------+---------------+
| Customer | Invoice No | Peding Amount | Total Pending |
+----------+------------+---------------+---------------+
| A        |          1 |            10 |          1110 |
| B        |          2 |           100 |           110 |
| C        |          3 |          1000 |          3020 |
| A        |          4 |          1000 |          1110 |
| A        |          5 |           100 |          1110 |
| B        |          6 |            10 |           110 |
| C        |          7 |          2000 |          3020 |
| C        |          8 |            20 |          3020 |
+----------+------------+---------------+---------------+
```

Now I would like to inform that the table only has first 3 columns but I need to add this 4th column but I am unable to find a way to have sum based on the customer.

Here is the code I am trying to use but I am getting some sort of syntax.

```
select 
 `tabSales Invoice`.`posting_date` as "Invoice Date:Date:80",
 `tabSales Invoice`.`due_date` as "Due Date:Date:80",
 `tabSales Invoice`.`name` as "Invoice No:Link/Sales Invoice:120",
 `tabSales Invoice`.`customer` as "Customer:Link/Customer:180",
 `tabSales Invoice`.`grand_total` as "Total:Currency:140",
 `tabSales Invoice`.`outstanding_amount` as "Pending:Currency:140",
 datediff(curdate(),`tabSales Invoice`.`posting_date`) as "Over By Invoice Date:Float:80",
 datediff(curdate(),`tabSales Invoice`.`due_date`) as "Over By Due Date:Float:80",
 `tabSales Invoice`.`debit_to` as "Customer Account:Link/Account:200"
from
 `tabSales Invoice`
where
 `tabSales Invoice`.`docstatus` = 1
 and `tabSales Invoice`.`outstanding_amount` > 0.005


Inner join(
    Select 
    `tabSales Invoice`.`customer`,
    SUM(`tabSales Invoice`.`outstanding_amount`) AS "Total Pending::180"
    from
     `tabSales Invoice`
     Group By
      `tabSales Invoice`.`customer`) 
     `tabSales Invoice` ON `tabSales Invoice`.`customer`
```

Comment: Is this *really* the resultset you're after (it's not very "relational" to repeat the same total across multiple records in the resultset)?  Or do you only need to know each customer and their respective total?  Or perhaps a running total?

Comment: So basically Total Pending = SUM (Pending Amount) group by Customer right? You can use a temporary table that will hold Customer Invoice No and PendingAmt and then calculate and update Total Pending colum like Set TotalPending = [select SUM(PendingAmt), Customer from temp group by customer] AS Customer where Customer = cust.Customer [cust]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this example...

```
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

 CREATE TABLE my_table
 (Customer CHAR(1) NOT NULL
 ,Invoice_No INT NOT NULL
 ,Pending_Amount INT NOT NULL
 ,PRIMARY KEY(Customer,Invoice_No)
 );

 INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
 ('A',1,10),
 ('B',2,100),
 ('C',3,1000,
 ('A',4,1000),
 ('A',5,100),
 ('B',6,10),
 ('C',7,2000),
 ('C',8,20);

 SELECT x.*
      , SUM(y.Pending_Amount) Total_Pending 
   FROM my_table x 
   JOIN my_table y 
     ON y.customer = x.customer 
  GROUP 
     BY x.customer
      , x.invoice_no;
 +----------+------------+----------------+---------------+
 | Customer | Invoice_No | Pending_Amount | Total_Pending |
 +----------+------------+----------------+---------------+
 | A        |          1 |             10 |          1110 |
 | A        |          4 |           1000 |          1110 |
 | A        |          5 |            100 |          1110 |
 | B        |          2 |            100 |           110 |
 | B        |          6 |             10 |           110 |
 | C        |          3 |           1000 |          3020 |
 | C        |          7 |           2000 |          3020 |
 | C        |          8 |             20 |          3020 |
 +----------+------------+----------------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subQuery

```
SELECT customer, invoiceno, pendingamount, pending
FROM mytable 
    INNER JOIN (
    SELECT customer, SUM(pendingamount) AS pending
    FROM mytable
    GROUP BY customer) a on mytable.customer ON a.customer
```